# Creating and linking a static library to another project. Small application size compared to the library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, static-libraries

I have a rather strange problem and I don't know if I'll be able to describe exactly but I'll try my best. I've never worked with static libraries so I don't have much experience here.

I have a code package with a lot of files created in C and of course header files. I pre-created a MakeFile to compile the resulting code into a static library. The structure of this MakeFile looks like this in a very brief way:

```
# makeLibrary.mk
# File       : Makefile for the static library 
#
GOAL    :=                  someName
BUILD   :=                  library
LIBTYPE :=                  static

SOURCES :=                  \
        file1.c             \
        file2.c             \
        file3.c             \
        file4.c             \
        file5.c             \
        file6.c 
CFLAGS  :=                  someFlags 
DEFINES :=                  someDefines 
INCLUDE_PATH := \
    ../export   
INSTALL_DIR        := ../releases/${ARCH}
HEADER_INSTALL_DIR := 
HEADER_FILES       :=
```

This results in the creation of files: file1.o, file2.o, ... , file6.o and one main library file: libsomeName.a.
The libsomeName.a file is about 614KB which is what I expected.
So far everything is ok for me.

Then I need to attach this library file to my project.
To create an executable application I will need another MakeFile so I created one. The structure of this MakeFile looks more then less like this:

```
# makeApplication.mk
# File       : Makefile for the executable application
#
GOAL    :=              executableApp
BUILD   :=              application
SOURCES :=              \
        myFile_main.c       

CFLAGS  :=              someFlags 
DEFINES :=              someDefines
```

Since I want to include a previously created library, I define it in this makeApplication.mk:

```
# Additional libraries, created in prev. makeLibrary.mk
STATLIBS := \
         someName
```

Since the created library and header files are in a different folder I define the location of these files:

```
#Library header file localization
INCLUDE_PATH := \
    ../../../export   
#Library file localization
LIBRARY_PATH := \
    ../../../releases/$(ARCH)
```

I think everything is ok so far.

And now my problem starts and I'm not sure if I understand correctly. I would like to use in *myFile_main.c* file functions which were added to *libsomeName.a* static library.
So, to do this I need to add header files in *myFile_main.c* file that belong to the library:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include "file3.h"
#include "file4.h"
#include "file5.h"
#include "file6.h"

...
//Here is some code where I use functions defined in the static library. The prototypes for these 
//functions are in the header files, of course.
...
```

All code compiles correctly without any errors and warnings. But what is created (executable application) worries me a little. The executableApp file is only 13KB.
Looking at the fact that the included library is 614KB it does not seem to be too reasonable.

When creating a static library, are there any more steps required to get everything right?

Why is the size of the application executable so small compared to the library itself?

I'm not able to test the application because the target is not ready yet. Is it possible to run/test such created application?

Answer (score 0):

When you link the final binary, it will not take everything inside the static library, instead only the stuff it actually needs is put into the binary.

So if you have two (independent) object files in the library, and you call one function, the one from the second object file will not be in the binary. Only when you also call it, it will copied inot the binary as well.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated. Do remove "dead code" you need more flags. But generally yes it will only link what is needed

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if in the whole created library there are about 1k functions but in the file myFile_main.c I use only a few ( +/-20) because it is only kernel initialization then in a generally only +/- 20 functions were included in the final executable file that is why the size is so "small"